# How to set vscode format golang code on save?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm using `vscode` with `Go` extensions to edit `golang` source code. Each time I want to format code, I have to press `Ctrl-Shift-i` on `linux`, `Shift-Alt-F` on `Windows`, or `Ctrl-Shift-p` and type `format`. Is it possible to set format on save, that is, when I press `ctrl-s`, it format the code automatically using `go.fmt` (or something alike)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should install this plugin: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go. One of the options is to set "auto format" on save: `go.formatOnSave": false`. It uses the Golang tooling for formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I was using this plugin, but I didn't find the options to set before asking this question. ` "go.formatOnSave": true` did the trick. I think the default setting should be `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: Another thing you should look at is changing "go.formatTool" from "go fmt" to "goimports" (and installing goimports).  Having it manage your imports is very handy (though use with caution, double-check it's importing the right thing).

Comment: does't work for me, check the answer below

Answer (score 40):

For me, none of the answers worked. My Go version is 1.17.1, VSCode version is 1.60.1 and I'm using Linux Pop!_os.

After some digging online found this in the official VSCode documentation for Go. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go#_formatting

My settings.json looks like this

```
"[go]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go"
},
```

Note: You need to install the required extensions for the go lang in VS code. Check the bottom left bar after opening a *.go file and you should see the go version. If you see an exclamation icon then click on it and install the suggested extensions.

Comment: "editor.defaultFormatter" was what I was missing - thanks!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Nice!

Comment: "editor.defaultFormatter" works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

From my visual code version, i cannot use config go.formatOnSave": false.

Then I can turn them off in settings as below:

- Build (Turn off using go.buildOnSave setting)
- Lint (Turn off using    go.lintOnSave setting)
- Vet (Turn off using go.vetOnSave setting)
- Format (Turn off by adding the below in your settings):

  > ```
  > "[go]": {
  >     "editor.formatOnSave": false 
  > }
  > ```

Comment: For Win: If you can not find it in VSCode then just go to %APPDATA%/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json and edit it manually. Works good since idk how to setup my own format for .go files

Comment: "[go]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false 
    }
Adding the above to my usersettings.json is what fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

For me the followed settings worked. I disabled the annoying import refactoring.

```
"[go]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": false
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This import organizer was so annoying